# Dynamically creating a dictionary from a single list of variables

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a dictionary in which the key is the name of a pandas dataframe and the value is the dataframe itself:

```
import pandas as pd

df_x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3]})
df_y = pd.DataFrame({'b':['a', 'b', 'c']})

dict_xy = dict({'df_x':df_x, 'df_y':df_y})
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this without having to write out each variable name twice (once as a string for the key and the other as a variable for the value)?

Comment: What about: `dict_xy = {'df_x': pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3]}), 'df_y': pd.DataFrame({'b':['a', 'b', 'c']})}`

Comment: @FiddlingBits Post that as an answer.

Comment: Actual use case has a massive number of dataframes which are created in an earlier process. So they already exist before the dictionary is created

Comment: Just create the dictionary, what is the point of the other variables?

Comment: What do you mean by a "massive number"? It seems like it wasn't so massive if you had to manually write out `df_i =...`

Comment: I want to loop over the dictionary a la what is discussed here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73084052/writing-multiple-dataframes-to-multiple-sheets-in-an-excel-file/

Comment: `..created in an earlier process..` - Have the DataFrames already been assigned to a *name* and you wish to associate those names as keys in the dictionary? Or are the *nameless* objects stored in a container, and you want to make names for them for use as dictionary keys. Need more information in your questipon.

Comment: I would name them as you create them, then add the names into a list or something similar.

Comment: You aren't answering any of our questions

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```py
dict_xy = {'df_x': pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3]}), 'df_y': pd.DataFrame({'b':['a', 'b', 'c']})}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dict comprehension

```
import pandas as pd

df_x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3]})
df_y = pd.DataFrame({'b':['a', 'b', 'c']})
dfs = [dfx, df_y]
dict_names = ['df_x', 'df_y']

dicts = {k:v for k, v in zip(dict_names, dfs)}
```

This should allow you to have many more than 2 dictionaries in your dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks but this still involves writing out the variable name twice (as a variable and then as a string, in each list respectively). This is what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

If your DataFrame variables are in the local namespace; iterate over `locals()` and create a dictionary of all the DataFrames.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> qrs = pd.DataFrame()
>>> locals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None,
 '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>,
 '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {},
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 'pd': <module 'pandas' from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py'>,
 'a': 'foo',
 'qrs': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []}
>>> isinstance(qrs,pd.DataFrame) 
True
>>> {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if isinstance(v,pd.DataFrame)}  
{'qrs': Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []}
>>>
```